# How to send base64Url encoded Raw Email message?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, gmail-api

I got Gmail RFC 2822 compliant message which contains everything (headers,body,subject etc.). The message is base64url encoded. I am trying to parse this message and send it to Exchange online. So far I have tried Sasa Mime library but this great library doesn't work for me.

```
string strRaw = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"G:\raw.txt");
var mail = Sasa.Net.Mail.Message.Parse(strRaw);
```

The above code fails with this following exception :
**Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length**

I request you to tell me which free Mime library I can use to parse Gmail Raw message. Java has a great built-in library called javax.mail.internet (MimeMessage class) which does the job very beautifully. I am using EWS managed Api to work with Exchange online and it's not able to parse Gmail raw message directly.

Edited : removed the encoded message.

best regards,

Comment: If the message is base64 encoded, you can just use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Aside from that: recommending libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow, since it often leads to discussions about which library is better. Google is less likely to start such discussions: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=c%23%20base%2064%20encoding

Comment: Sir, I already using base64url encoder-decoder functions. C# doesn't have built-in support for such functions,however they have function to encode/decode base64 nor base64url. My problem is I am not able to parse gmail raw message to exchange readable format. So that I can send  this raw message to exchange programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you indicated the string is base64url you have to adapt slightly to overcome the difference from orginal base64 as indicated in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

The following table shows the differences:

```
standard  | 62 | 63 | pad
-------------------------
base64    | +  | /  | =
base64Url | -  | _  | N/A
```

Using this knowledge it becomes clear how to convert from a base64Url to the base64 standard that is used by [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx).

This code shows how that could work:

```
var base64Url = "UmVjZWl2 ..... rest of your base64url string ... -";

// replace - and _ with their base64 chars
var sb64 = new StringBuilder(base64Url)
              .Replace('-','+')
              .Replace('_', '/');
var bin = Convert.FromBase64String(sb64.ToString());    

Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bin).Dump("valid");
```

Using above code dumped the following result in my console (part of it):

> Received: from removed.googleusercontent.com
>     named unknown
>     by gmailapi.google.com
>     with HTTPREST;
>     Sat, 29 Nov 2014 04:55:31 -0800
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   x-no-auto-attachment: 1
>   Received: by 10.114.186.6; Mon, 17 Nov 2014 07:11:34 -0800 (PST) 
>   Date: Sat, 29 Nov 2014 04:55:31 -0800
>   Message-Id: [removed for privacy]
>   Subject: Tips for using your new inbox
>   From: [removed for privacy]
>   To: "Your Team @365innovate" <[removed for privacy] >
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c33c7aee86ee05080f6437
>
> --001a11c33c7aee86ee05080f6437
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Tips for using your new inbox
>   [image: Google]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send inline images in emails using Microsoft EWS service, you can send the image as an attachment and set it as inline. Following is a step by step guide to convert a MIMEMessage to EmailMessage format - https://azaylamba.medium.com/converting-mimemessage-to-emailmessage-while-sending-email-using-microsoft-ews-service-a-57137e281f53

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34456288)